# Запрос на получение ссылки

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Как получить `href` ссылку из https://bookvoed.ee/search?q=white+fang?

```
x = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "o-row"})
for link in x:
    link = link.find('a').get('href')
    print(link)
```

Код выводит не то, что нужно

[image: x]

Comment: Код выглядит правильно, но: 1) данных может и не быть 2) может вы нашли другие данные . Приведите ссылку для тестирования

Comment: https://bookvoed.ee/search?q=white+fang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что ваш поиск возвращал первый тег `<a>`, а т.к. поиск был только по тегу, то и получали первый попавшийся.

Нужно было в поиске указывать `class='title'`.

CSS-селектор:

- `.o-row` – поиск элементов с `class="o-row"`
- `a.title` – поиск элементов с `<a class="title">`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c434c2dfac74fb5d98b693b8b47b1298d1ee2a2e/html_parsing/bookvoed_ee__search.py#L16)

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://bookvoed.ee/search?q=white+fang')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for row in root.select('.o-row'):
    a = row.select_one('a.title')
    href = urljoin(rs.url, a.get('href'))
    title = a.get_text(strip=True)
    print(title, href)

# White Fang https://bookvoed.ee/goods/4496177
# Белый клык = White Fang https://bookvoed.ee/goods/6807168
# The Call of the Wild and White Fang https://bookvoed.ee/goods/8654867
# White Fang [= Белый Клык] https://bookvoed.ee/goods/451827
# Call of the Wild & White Fang https://bookvoed.ee/goods/4914246
```

---

**PS.**

В `href` хранятся относительные ссылки, поэтому для удобства добавил код конвертирования в абсолютные ссылки через `urljoin`